# Why is numpy.exp() giving an Overflow warning in this case?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following reproducible script:

```py
import numpy as np

c0, c1 = 0.000032, 3

S_test = np.ones((3,3), dtype=float)*300000
S_test[1,1] = 2000


np.where(S_test > 2000, 1, 1 - 1 / np.exp((c0 * S_test) ** c1) )

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

array([[1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e+00, 2.62109643e-04, 1.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

I am trying to figure out 1) Why I am getting this overflow error and 2) how can it be dealt with in a way that doesn't just ignore it because i'm not entirely certain what the consequences of ignoring it are in the first place.

The `np.where()` should first recognize where `S_test > 2000` and then return 1 for those values, alternatively, where this condition does not hold `np.where()` should return `1 - 1 / np.exp((c0 * S_test) ** c1)`

I have tried to separately compute `1 - 1 / np.exp((c0 * 2000) ** c1)` and this evaluates just fine and as I expected.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: In Python, all the arguments of a function are evaluated **before** they are passed to the function.  So the `cond` does not prevent the evaluation, in full, of the other arguments.  `np.exp`, as a `ufunc` does take its own `where` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

np.where evaluates both operands.

If you really want to avoid the warning, you can do e.g. something like this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/_lib/_util.py#L31

Comment: Oh I see, so for ```np.where(condition, x, y)``` it computes both x and y at the same time, and then depending on how the condition evaluates it will return either x or y, so that must be why the overflow error is occuring. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Nearly, yes. I'd only say "fills the output array with elementa of x or y" instead of "returns either x or y".

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because all arguments of `np.where` are fully evaluated. You can do this:

```
S_test_capped = np.where(S_test > 2000, 2000, S_test)
np.where(S_test > 2000, 1, 1 - 1 / np.exp((c0 * S_test_capped) ** c1) )
```

or just silence the warnings:

```
old_settings = np.seterr(over='ignore')
np.where(S_test > 2000, 1, 1 - 1 / np.exp((c0 * S_test) ** c1) )
np.seterr(**old_settings) # restore warning settings
```